# ANTLR4 Custom class for ParserRuleContexts

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr4

ANTLR generates contexts derived from `ParserRuleContext`. We have an amount of extra logic and modified behaviour that we want applied to each context. Is it possible to subclass `ParserRuleContext` and somehow tell ANTLR to generate contexts using the custom base class instead? Either for all, or ideally, on a context by context basis. I have so far only found documentation to change the class of the parser itself.

At the moment we are using the way the contexts are declared as partial and injecting the code by writing in another partial class. This needs to be done once per context so there's a lot of repetition and it isn't very nice.

Comment: Why don't you use extension methods? This should be fine as long as you don't need additional fields.

Comment: Some of the methods need to be overriden to change their behaviour, so can't use extensions unfortunately.

Comment: Not certain this is an acceptable alternative. You can add a [property](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/CSharp/runtime/CSharp/Antlr4.Runtime/Tree/ParseTreeProperty.cs) to context nodes.  The value of the property can be an object with any fields and methods desired.  Easy enough to walk the parse tree and add context type dependent objects to the nodes desired.  Or, create an independent map between context node instances and your desired 'extension' objects. Again, use a parse tree walk to fill in the map and invoke as appropriate.